# starting a sentence with i mean for no reason

Tags: meaning, idioms

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/i-mean

> "Do people think what the country did was wrong?" "**I mean,** they were the
> worst of the worst, because they completely made up lies about their
> war crimes, which was worse than anything any country has done back
> then."

You usually use "I mean" to clarify, but sometimes I use it for no reason when I can just remove it and it would make a lot more sense since I didn't mention anything related to that beforehand.

Comment: What is your question? There is no reason to use it when you are not clarifying something, but Cambridge mentions that usage because it exists.

Comment: In your context, introductory ***I mean*** is an almost content-devoid ***filler, discourse marker, noise word,...*** It would make no difference whatsoever to the meaning of the cited text if that element were discarded completely, or replaced by something equally "meaningless" (pun intended! :) in context, such as ***I think...***